# Python Pandas Index error: List Index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, syntax-error

My code worked on a previous dataset and now stopped working. I looked through other answers for this error message, but none seems applicable to mine.

I have one column in my dataframe df for Email_Address and I would like to just split the domain out into a new columns.

My dataframe is a subset of a previous df.

```
#create new df, for only email addresses I need to review
df = df_raw.loc[df_raw['Review'] == 'Y'].copy()

#I reset the index to fix the problem, but it didnt help
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#ensure Email Address is a string
df['Email_Address']= df.Email_Address.apply(str)

#make Email Address lower case
df['email_lowercase'] = df['Email_Address'].str.lower()

#Split out domain into a new column 
df['domain'] = df['email_lowercase'].apply(lambda x: x.split('@')[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This might mean that the symbol `@` doesn't exist in one of your cell so that you can't access the part of the email that is 'after' the `@`. Sometimes users type `at` instead of `@` so they can't be traced by bots. Have you checked for that?

Comment: Im not sure but try changing this `df['Email_Address']= df.Email_Address.apply(str)` to this `df['Email_Address']= df.Email_Address.astype(str)`  Its also possible you have non-clean data where there is no data on some rows after `@` which would cause it to fail.  Check that too.

Comment: without a representative `df`, it's impossible to reproduce your error.  Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have invalid emails in your dataframe. 
You can identify these by using

```
df[~df.Email_Address.astype(str).str.contains('@')]
```

You could use this approach to extract the domain

```
def extract_domain(email):
    email_domain = email.split('@')
    if len(email_domain) > 1:
        return email_domain[1]

df['domain'] = df['email_lowercase'].apply(extract_domain)
```

or even shorter:

```
df['domain'] = df['email_lowercase'].str.split('@').apply(lambda li: li[1] if len(li) > 1 else None)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: @jeangelj I fixed this. (forgot `str.` before `contains`)

Comment: Thank you, it seems there are some Nan surprisingly - I made them into 0s